# Strikethrough in Terminal Emacs

Tags: unicode, emacs

I'm trying to get a strikethrough to work in terminal emacs. When I add a strikethrough via the `face` route, nothing happens. I can, however, paste text with a strikethrough into emacs and it renders correctly. When I `describe-char` on it, it says (done with <strike>`i`</strike>):

```
Composed with the following character(s) "̶" by these characters:  
i (#x69)
- (#x336)
```

I know that many terminals can't handle strikethroughs, but I know mine can, because you can paste them into it. I'm struggling to understand why editing the face doesn't work but I can paste strikethroughs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to insert composing characters to strike out, such that you're changing the contents of the buffer.  I don't think I got all the corner cases, but this is a start:

```
(defun strikeout-region (b e)
  "Use \"COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY\" unicode char to strike out the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (when (use-region-p)
    (save-mark-and-excursion
      (goto-char b)
      (while (and (<= (point) e)
                (not (eobp)))
        (unless (looking-back "[[:space:]]" (1- (point)))
          (insert-char #x336)
          (setq e (1+ e)))
        (forward-char 1)))))
```

But maybe you're trying to display a certain face (as set through e.g. font-lock), then setting the strike-through property is the right way to do this.  My terminal (rxvt-unicode) can display the composed characters too, but I can't get it to display a face with strike-through.